# Proper way to add a new database in a django project

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I'm trying to add some databases to my django project, basically I have a simple "online shop" with the default database that django creates when you make a new project. I use the default database to store new users. Now, I want to add new databases, for example, for a new line of products like bikes. So the settings.py looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'bikes': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'USER': 'asd',
        'PASSWORD': 'asd',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'bikesdb.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

The thing is, supposedly, there has to be a "bikesdb.sqlite3" in the same folder that "db.sqlite3" is. How do I add this .sqlite3 file? Just simple as creating it? Do I have to run a django shell command? I've tried with "migrate" and "makemigrations" commands but the file does not appear. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not just add a new Model to your default DB?

Comment: Yeah, that's an option, but i want to know how to create multiple databases for one project